# Disassemble instruction with a variable as an offset

Tags: disassembly, idapython

I am looking to disassemble an instruction at an address. I know that there are many instructions that can accomplish this such as `idc.GetDisasm()`, `idc.GetDisasmEx()`, `idaapi.generate_disassembly()`, etc.

When I disassemble a line that has a variable in it, the variable appears in the disassembly. ie `38 81 00 38` disassembles as `addi r4, r1, 0x80+var_48` instead of `addi r4, r1, 0x38`.

Is there any way to disassemble this in the latter form ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to set the operand type, there are various functions to accomplish that. [OpHex](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc-module.html#OpHex) is most likely what you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This could work if it is called for each instruction. However, two problems arise with it. A) I would like to restore it to the way it was prior to converting it with OpHex. B) OpHex/OpOff etc.. does not convert the operand of a branch.

Answer (score 1):

not idapython but idc

```
auto i;

for (  i = MinEA() ; i < MaxEA() ; i = NextHead(i, MaxEA()) )
{
    OpHex(i,-1);
}
```

take a look here for bit more details

[Convert [arg8+foo-blah+28] to [ebp+38]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199403/differences-in-ollydbg-and-ida-pro-for-movsx-edx-byte-ptr-especx8-command/23604013#23604013)